# $G'(\pi)$ is the smallest normal subgroup with an Abelian $\pi$-factor group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to show that following claim stated in Kurzweil and Stellmacher:

> Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, let $P$ be a Hall $\pi$-subgroup of $G$ and let $G'(\pi)$ be the inverse image of $O_{\pi'}(G/G')$ in $G$. Then $G'(\pi)$ is the smallest normal subgroup with an Abelian $\pi$-factor group.

Here $\pi'$ is the set of all primes not in $\pi$ and $O_{\pi'}(G/G')$ is the smallest Hall $\pi'$-subgroup of $G/G'$ (alternatively, the largest normal $\pi'$-subgroup).

**My attempt:** Since inverse image of a normal subgroup is normal, so $G'(\pi)$ is normal in $G$. Moreover, as $O_{\pi'}(G/G')$ is a subgroup of $G/G'$, so $G'\subseteq G'(\pi)$ and $O_{\pi'}(G/G')=G'(\pi)/G'$. In particular, $G'(\pi)/G'$ is Abelian. Using
$$|G/G'(\pi)|=\frac{|G/G'|}{|G'(\pi)/G'|},$$ we obtain that $G/G'(\pi)$ is a $\pi$-group.

Finally, let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/N$ is an Abelian $\pi$-group. We need to show that $G'(\pi)\subseteq N$.

---

I'm not able to show the last part.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $O_{\pi'}(G/G')$?

Comment: @Shaun Smallest Hall $\pi'$-subgroup of $G/G'$ (alternatively, the largest normal $\pi'$-subgroup).

Comment: Thank you. I suggest you [edit] the post accordingly.

Comment: This is very similar to one of your previous questions. If not, then we would have $G' \le N$, and  $G'(\pi)N/N$ would be a $p'$-subgroup of the $p$-group $G/N$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, but I was not able to show that $G'(\pi)N/N$ is a $\pi'$-subgroup.

Comment: That follows from $G' \le N$ and $G'(\pi)/G'$ is a $\pi'$-group.

Comment: @DerekHolt But this only gives that order of $|G'(\pi)N/N|=|G'(\pi)|/|G'(\pi)\cap N|\geq |G'(\pi)|/G'|$. So prime factors of $|G'(\pi)N/N|$ can still be other than those of $G'(\pi)/G'$?

Comment: No, $G' \le N$ implies that $G'(\pi)N/N$ is isomorphic to a quotient group of $G'(\pi)/G'$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't understand.

Comment: You should think about it a bit more, it is just application of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: @DerekHolt I mean I don't understand your sentence. Do you mean it is isomorphic to a quotient subgroup of $G'(\pi)/G'$. What does "a quotient group of $G'(\pi)/G'$" mean?

Comment: Surely you know what a quotient group is? It's sometimes called a factor group.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think I got it. Because $G'\subseteq N$, so the natural map from $G'(\pi)/G'$ to $G'(\pi)N/N$ is an onto homomorphim. Thus, order of range divides order of domain.

Comment: It can be helpful to draw the lattice of all the subgroups under consideration. Then you can more easily visualize the inclusions and isomorphisms.